# How to find an equation of all planes that pass through two points?

Tags: 3d, plane-geometry

How to find an equation of all planes that pass through points $(a,0,a^2)$ and $(a^{-1},0,a^{-2})$? I know that there are infinity of them, but can we write it down in one equation, possibly using some variables?

---

I found two planes that pass through these points: one is x-z plane and it is given by equation $y=0$, and second plane passes through these points and also perpendicular to x-z plane and it is given by equation $z=(a+a^{-1})x-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you already did most of the job.

Multiply the equation of the first plane by $\sin\varphi$, the second one by $\cos\varphi$, and add both together. That would be your single equation with a parameter ($\varphi$).

$$y\sin\varphi + z\cos\varphi - x\left(a+\frac1a\right)\cos\varphi+\cos\varphi = 0$$

How so?

Well, both equations are certainly true at both points, hence so is any linear combination of them. Our resulting plane passes through both points as well.

How do I know that the equation covers *all* such planes?

Why, just find the angle between my plane and your second plane, and realize that it is $\varphi$. By varying $\varphi$, you rotate my plane around the line that connects  the two points.

So it goes.

Comment: thanks, I got the idea